# Pass value to router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On my web-app I have a dashboard route:

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    parent: 'root',
    abstract: true,
    redirectTo: 'dashboard.tasks',
    views: {
        'new@': {
            templateUrl: '/Modules/Dashboard/Dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        }
    },
    onEnter: [ () => {
        console.log('dashboard enter');
        if (passedThroughValue === 'timeline') {
            console.log('dashboard enter from timeline');
        }
    }]
});
```

From my `timeline.html` I have this link:

```
ui-sref="dashboard.tasks.overview.details.information({ id: activity.task.id })"
```

When I click the I'm routed to the dashboard state and I see the `dashboard enter` console log. But obviously not the `dashboard enter from timeline`.

How do I pass a string value in that link to the router state so I can catch from where the user is navigating to the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$stateParams` into your `onEnter` and than read it's properties

```
onEnter: ['$stateParams', ($stateParams) => {
    console.log('dashboard enter');
    if ($stateParams.passedThroughValue === 'timeline') {
        console.log('dashboard enter from timeline');
    }
}]
```

You can then pass `passedThroughValue` when you redirect with `ui-sref`

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams [Please go through this link guide,angularjs has its own RouteParam which allows you to pass the value through the link]

Comment: he is asking about uiRouter, not ngRouter